# Firebase packages and plugins breaking Flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm having major trouble when using Firebase packages within my app. Now on iOS my app will not compile. I think it started since I updated Xcode but don't know why that would be the problem. I've been stuck on it for over a week.

The two packages causing a problem are:

- firebase_storage ^3.0.6
- cloud_firestore 0.12.9+4

None of the other Firebase packages cause a problem.

- firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
- firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
- firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6
- firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+1
- cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+1

The error I get is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 7 in debug mode... Xcode build done.
103.6s Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
    2019-10-01 05:54:27.049 xcodebuild[80532:1543780]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 6aa0c9719a85c174869a09656237b42f23701a91 was NULL
    2019-10-01 05:54:27.192 xcodebuild[80532:1543775]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 6aa0c9719a85c174869a09656237b42f23701a91 was NULL
    2019-10-01 05:54:27.643 xcodebuild[80532:1543780]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 023ad015ab9ce7b62b0a4e86af10805b3ef8fdb4 was NULL
    2019-10-01 05:54:28.935 xcodebuild[80532:1543771] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 023ad015ab9ce7b62b0a4e86af10805b3ef8fdb4 was NULL
    2019-10-01 05:54:28.944 xcodebuild[80532:1543771] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 023ad015ab9ce7b62b0a4e86af10805b3ef8fdb4 was NULL
    2019-10-01 05:54:28.951 xcodebuild[80532:1543771] [MT] DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 023ad015ab9ce7b62b0a4e86af10805b3ef8fdb4 was NULL
    ** BUILD FAILED ** Xcode's output: ↳
    /Users/earyzhe/dev/FlutterProjects/Mini exercises/Firebase Projects/firebase_compile_test/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/earyzhe/dev/FlutterProjects/Mini exercises/Firebase Projects/firebase_compile_test/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:19:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/earyzhe/dev/FlutterProjects/Mini exercises/Firebase Projects/firebase_compile_test/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:20:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
    /Users/earyzhe/dev/FlutterProjects/Mini exercises/Firebase Projects/firebase_compile_test/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:21:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
     #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
             <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
    3 warnings generated.
    /Users/earyzhe/dev/FlutterProjects/Mini exercises/Firebase Projects/firebase_compile_test/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
```

**This actually carries on like this for another 100 lines or so, basically repeating similarly.**

I would really appreciate the help as this is blocking a product release and cannot find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Try not specifying the version number, just put any